# SQL Server - How to get round false Multiple Cascade paths on Update Only (Not Deletes)?

Tags: sql-server, cascade

I have 2 tables, one for Users & one for Orders, laid out like this:

```
**Users**
Username

**Orders**
MadeBy     NOT NULL     (on Delete - No Action  on Update - Cascade)
ApprovedBy NULL         (on Delete - Set NULL   on Update - Cascade)
```

As you can see, both fields relate back to the same field in the Usernames table, but they may be different from each other, i.e. User1 makes the order, and User2 approves it. Both of the child fields to not link to anywhere else in the database.

I'm getting the following error:

```
'Users' table saved successfully
'Orders' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Orders_ApprovedBy'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Orders_ApprovedBy' on table 'Orders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

This only occurs when I set the second of the two foreign keys' (in this case, ApprovedBy) Update Rule to Cascade. It's fine with the Delete rule (Presumably because they're different).

How should I get around this? I've read about using Triggers, but i'm unsure how/where I should be applying them to, and what the syntax is for referring back to an previous value that's just been changed.

This is the code that SQL Management studio is using to apply the final change (setting the FK_Orders_ApprovedBy Update rule to Cascade):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Orders ADD CONSTRAINT
FK_Orders_ApprovedBy FOREIGN KEY
(
ApprovedBy
) REFERENCES dbo.Users
(
UserName
) ON UPDATE  CASCADE 
 ON DELETE  SET NULL 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Orders SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having these constraints?

Comment: So that if a user's username is changed, it propagates through to any instances of it occurring in those two fields in the orders table.

Comment: Can you post the t-SQL you're using to create the tables?

Comment: That's ok, most gui tasks in ssms have an option to script the action out to a query window or file or clipboard.

Comment: Got it, i've updated the OP with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get the same error when trying to set both `ON DELETE` to `CASCADE`. So if it's a requierment there's no option but `INSTEAD OF` trigger. (Or do it with some app layer, SPs or something).
Next updating PK is rather uncommon scenario. Generally evrething that could be updated during the entity life cycle must not interfer with PK. The only role PK should play is just "there exists an entity". Check your design please.